# Remove duplicates in cells from specific columns in R?

Tags: r, unique, rows, bioinformatics, numeric

[image]

I have a data frame which contains repeated characters or numbers. I want to create a new df which only contains unique cells in each of these columns. Below is a visual of what I am trying to achieve. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: See here: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>

Comment: Use the function `distinct` of the package `dplyr`.

Comment: Thank you Marcos. However how can I use distinct in a specific column to keep in each cell of that row unique results?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex solution (based on mock data in the absence of reproducible data):

```
library(stringr)
df[,1:3] <- lapply(df[,1:3], function(x) str_extract_all(x, "(\\b\\w+\\b)(?!.*\\1)"))
```

The solution drwas on negative lookahead (`(?!...)`) and backreference (`\\1`): the pattern `(\\b\\w+\\b)(?!.*\\1)` is used to `str_extract_all` alphanumeric strings *unless they are repeated* later in the string, which effectively captures all unique values:

Result:

```
df
               Title   Length    Prediction
1             George 555, 666           111
2 Alice, Peter, Kate 123, 444 333, 777, 222
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Title = c("George,George,George", "Kate,Alice,Kate,Peter,Kate"),
  Length = c("555,555,666", "123,123,444,123,444"), 
  Prediction = c("111,111,111", "222,333,222,777,222"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.  Using the `df` [created](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66956406/2884859) by ChrisRuehlemann

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~str_split(., ",")),
              across(everything(), ~map(., ~unique(.x))))
               Title   Length    Prediction
1             George 555, 666           111
2 Kate, Alice, Peter 123, 444 222, 333, 777
```

Or one-liner

```
mutate(df, across(everything(), ~map(str_split(., ","), ~unique(.x))))

               Title   Length    Prediction
1             George 555, 666           111
2 Kate, Alice, Peter 123, 444 222, 333, 777
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The only problem when using this solution is that it gives it in a format of c("", "", "") for the rows that had different values, for example before it was: 765, 765, 837, 837, 837, 762, 762 and then after the code you suggested it turns into: c("765", "837", "762")

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to fix to not contain it in this format?

Comment: This can be tackled.  Please give an example data instead of image.